# Is there a way to have Choice user input type for "For a selected item" flow trigger?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have two SharePoint lists:

List 1 - has item details
List 2 - has shipping details

As one item can be shipped to different locations, List 1 has one to many relationship with List 2. I have a trigger a flow button in List 1 to create a shipping list item in List 2, with following details:

Shipped date
NumberofShippedItems
Shipped to Location
Courier
TrackingNumber

As the title suggests, I need "Shipped to Location" to be a choice field to pass as user input as the user clicks the trigger button in List 1. However I dont see that in "For a selected Item" trigger in Power Automate. Is there a workaround for this? People can make mistakes while entering locations (we use two letter notations assigned to each location).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Unfortunately, choice is not yet supported as an input in the "for a selected file" trigger.</s>

**Update**

We can display a choice field when triggering a Flow by using the **Input**. After it's added, we need to click on the "..." button and then click "Add a drop-down list of options"

[image]

[image]

Comment: that is a shame. Is there any user voice recommendation already created?

Comment: @AykutKaraca I found a way to do it. Updated my answer